# Need suggestions creating a random name for wordpress blog author

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

Hi I have a website that uses a variety of blog writers that basically create drafts, upload them and I review them, I post them when ready, and it displays the author as (.... by COMPANY) I would love to not do that.

What would a good way be to have my site randomly pick a first name like Jim or Bob, as the author, rather than my company as the author. This is a wordpress site. Is there a plugin out there someone could suggest? or perhaps some javascript code? Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: If you'd read the title, I'm looking for suggestions, thanks

Comment: How about this service? http://www.fakenamegenerator.com/  If you google there are similar services with REST API.

Comment: Create a custom field for fake author name. Use a template where default user is not shown but custom field is shown. If you search google for how to get custom fields set-up in wordpress, you will get good sample code. Good luck!

Comment: @KenjiNoguchi I would like to not have to manually go into all my blogs and use that generator, if possible I would like to put it in my php code so it does it very every blog, past and future

Comment: So create an array of names in your php code, and pick a random one when creating a post? What's the problem you're having?

Comment: Questions asking for recommendations like this are specifically [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) on StackOverflow

Comment: It would seem stack overflow is not the place to come to for help anymore. sad day. back to google.

Comment: @user3688814 it doesn't sound like you were really after help, just somebody to do it for you. StackOverflow [isn't the place for questions](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) of "I want to do this, show me how". If you explain in your question how you've at least tried to solve the problem yourself, you'll find people are much more receptive and willing to help. Personally if someone has at least tried something, I'm more than happy to help guide them to what they're after. If it doesn't look like they've even tried to find an answer, why should I?

Comment: Fair enough. I'm not a coder. and was tired of google searching. But I ended up finding a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a simple database approach:

```
FAKENAMES
| id |fake_name | lastused |
| 1  | Jake     | x        |
| 2  | Julie    | x        |
| 3  | James    | me       |
| 4  | John     | x        |
```

....you could have a hundred

then dynamicaly assign like this

```
1.) ACCESSS YOUR DATABASE & 
  // Get FAKENAMES
  $getFAKENAMES = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * 
                                            FROM FAKENAMES 
                                            ");

2.) Prepare the title variable

  $title = '';  // we will leave it blank for just a sec...

  while(lastUSED = myslqi_fetch_array($getFAKENAMES)){

      if($lastUSED['lastused'] == me){
      $lasttitleWAS = current($lastUSED['fake_name'])
      $title .= next($lastUSED['fake_name']) //Set Title to next fakename 
      }

      // Set Newly used FakeName as Used       
      mysqli_query($connection,"UPDATE FAKENAMES 
                                SET lastused=me 
                                WHERE fake_name='$title'");      

      // Free up Previous used FakeName as by renaming to x       
      mysqli_query($connection,"UPDATE FAKENAMES 
                                SET lastused=x 
                                WHERE fake_name='$lasttitleWAS'"); 
   }
```

Then insert new title it into your webpage

```
  <title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
```

Hope this helps!